# R seems to ignore the last line of .Rprofile?

Tags: r

It is very strange that R appears to ignore the last line of my `.Rprofile`.

For example, in `.Rprofile`

```
 ...
 test<-function()1 # without line ending
```

And thus `test` is never loaded although the rest is loaded successfully. If I load it manually, `source(".Rprofile")`, `test` loads fine.

Is it the desired behaviour?

Under R studio with R 3.0 + in Linux

Can any one reproduce this?

Comment: See https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4056

Answer (score 14):

This is a super annoying "feature" - the last line is silently ignored if it does not have a trailing newline.

Comment: is a \n a newline character?